# Prove that $a ⊈ \{a\}$, where $a$ is non-empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I show it like this.

Assume, $a \subseteq \{a\}$

Let $x \in a.~$ Then $x \in \{a\}  (∵ a \subseteq \{a\})$

And we know $a \in \{a\}$

$\therefore x \in a \in \{a\}$

$∴ x ∉ {a}$.

This is a contradiction!

$a \subseteq \{a\}$ is false.$~∴ a ⊈ \{a\}$ is true.

Is this method right or wrong? If there is another way to prove it?

Comment: Why $x\in a\in\{a\}$ implies $x\notin \{a\}$?

Comment: What is $a$?  I ask because if $a$ is arbitrary, then this is false: $$\emptyset\subseteq \{\emptyset\}\,.$$  In fact, the only possible set $a$ such that $a\subseteq \{a\}$ is $a=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Batominovski  If we *aren't* using ZFC then $a = \{a\}$ is also a case where $a\subset \{a\}$.  Of course $a = \{a\}$ is not particularly very well defined.

Comment: @fleablood  Agreed, but I am assuming that most people are familiar with ZFC, so the setting is probably with ZFC.

Comment: Not that $\{a\}$ has two subsets.  $\emptyset$ and $\{a\}$.  If $a\subset \{a\}$ then either $a = \emptyset$ and $\{a\} =\{\emptyset\}$. This is certainly valid and possible.  Or $a = \{a\}$ which violates ZFC.

Comment: To critique your proof:  1)You don't explain why why $x\in a\in\{a\}$ implies $x \not \in \{a\}$.  After all $x \in \{x\} \in \{x,\{x\}\}$ and so $x \in \{x,\{x\}\}$ is perfectly valid.  2) when you say $x \in a$ you aren't taking into account that $a$ may be empty.  If you *do* get a contradiction then you conclusion has to be that $a$ is empty.  Which leads to 3) the statement is not true; if $a$ is empty then $a=\emptyset \subset \{a\}=\{\emptyset\}$ is a true and valid statement.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is incorrect. For one thing: the inclusion $a\subseteq\{a\}$ is obviously true if $a=\emptyset$.

If you assume that $a\ne\emptyset$, then your idea works, but for a different reason than you believe. If $x\in a$, then $x\in\{a\}$, by transitivity of inclusion, hence $x=a$. Thus $a\in a$, which is ruled out by the axiom of foundation (or regularity).

If the axiom of foundation is not assumed, then it is impossible to prove the statement (when restricted to nonempty $a$), because there might exist sets such that $a=\{a\}$.

Comment: I want to put a comment on the use of the axiom of regularity: using it is necessary as sets of the form $a=\{a\}$ could exist if we do not assume regularity. (Sets of the form $a=\{a\}$ are called *Quine atoms*.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, of course you're right. In “standard mathematics” regularity is usually assumed. More precisely, the most commonly used versions of ZFC include regularity. On the other hand, if the OP wants to prove $a\not\subseteq\{a\}$ (for nonempty $a$), regularity has to be assumed as per your comment itself.

Comment: Regularity is standard for most *standard* set theories, but I do not think it is standard for most mathematics. As Andreas Blass mentioned in his article *The interaction between set theory and category theory*, most mathematicians do not care and just simply ignore this unfortunate axiom.

Comment: @HanulJeon I fully agree. On the other hand, as I added to my answer, regularity *is* necessary for proving the statement to begin with (provided restricted to nonempty sets).